# Why Contour area only return 0?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to find the contour area, but contour area only returns `0` 
whatever the contour is. 
no error shows.

```
void CMFC_DEMODlg::OnBnClickedRun()
{
    CString str;

    IplImage* src1    = cvLoadImage("onlyone001.JPG",1);
    IplImage* src2    = cvLoadImage("b004.JPG",1);
    IplImage* grey    = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src2), 8, 1 );
    IplImage* dst    = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src2), 8, 3 );
    IplImage* F        = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src2), 8, 1 );
    IplImage* W        = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src2), 8, 1 );

    cvCvtColor( src2, grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvThreshold( grey, W,200,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    CvSeq* c;
    CvSeq* contour;
    CvSeq* result;

    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    int Nc = cvFindContours(
    W,
    storage,
    &contour,
    sizeof(CvContour),
    CV_RETR_LIST,
    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
    cvPoint(0,0));

    double Area;

    result = cvApproxPoly(contour, sizeof(CvContour), storage,
        CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contour)*0.02, 0);

    Area = fabs(cvContourArea(result, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));

    str.Format("Area: %d\n", Area);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC02)-&gt;SetWindowText(str);

    str.Format("Nc: %d\n", Nc);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC01)-&gt;SetWindowText(str);


    m_CvvImage.CopyOf(src2,1);
    m_CvvImage.DrawToHDC(Disp_hDC1,Disp_Rect);

    m_CvvImage.CopyOf(src1,1);
    m_CvvImage.DrawToHDC(Disp_hDC2,Disp_Rect);

    m_CvvImage.CopyOf(W,1);
    m_CvvImage.DrawToHDC(Disp_hDC3,Disp_Rect);
}
```

I simply want to calculate the area of each contour in my image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be useful to show a picture with contours drawn - for example, the contour area won't calculate correctly for contours with self intersections.

Comment: cvContourArea returns a double.

Comment: thank you sir.problem solve

Comment: but i have another question,
if theres not only one contour in the photo,
how to find the contour area that i want?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443436/opencv-countour-area-returns-zero?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The points should be placed in the vector in a clock-wise sequence.
Take a square for example:

```
corners2.push_back(Point(0,0));
corners2.push_back(Point(src.rows-1,0));
corners2.push_back(Point(src.rows-1,src.cols-1));
corners2.push_back(Point(1,src.cols-1));
```